# Как оценить результат работы Яндекс-танк?

Tags: яндекс-танк

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Яндекс-танк выдал такую статистику в итоге, но непонятно, плохо ли отвечает сервер или это приемлимо, и вообще правильную ли нагрузку я задал, как определить для себя какой-то гайд по работе с этим инструментом?

Кстати, когда я зашел на localhost:8080 у меня не работала метрика, словно по этому порту ничего не было запущено, а в описании к инструменту читал, что там будут строиться графики и будет более менее понятен консольный вывод

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у танка нет итогового отчета, консольный вывод предназначен в основном для посекундого вывода статистики (кроме некоторых полей)

Чтобы ответить на вопрос плохо ли, хорошо ли отвечает сервис, нужно сначала определиться что вы хотите проверить.
Думаю вам стоит посмотреть https://events.yandex.ru/lib/talks/2717/ чтобы понять какие тесты обычно стоит проводить.

Про графики: танк может лить данные в https://overload.yandex.net (там же есть инструкция по подключению).

btw: танк получил 302 для 100% запросов, сетевых ошибок не было.
Вероятнее всего вы рассчитывали посылать запросы возвращающие 200 - посмотрите что именно шлет танк, открыв сгенеренный танком stpd файл. В tank.log можно посмотреть куда именно его положил танк.

Comment: Зачем нам нужен stpd файл? Почему нельзя из load.ini сделать какой-то вывод о посылаемых запросах? Да, графики на overload.yandex.net я получил, опять же, как понять, что так или не так в этих графиках?

Comment: stpd файл - это входной файл для генератора нагрузки phantom, он содержит размер запроса, время когда нужно его задать и сам запрос.

Comment: load.ini - это конфигурация танка, она отвязана от содержимого запросов. Это сделано намеренно, потому что танк это обертка над различными генераторами нагрузки, которые могут иметь разный формат входных данных, для jmeter-а или bfg это вообще сценарии, а не запросы в явном виде.  https://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core_and_modules.html#modules - вот тут можно почитать о модульной архитектуре танка.

Comment: "Да, графики на overload.yandex.net я получил, опять же, как понять, что так или не так в этих графиках?" - запишем позже обзорную лекцию по оверлоаду.